# Python - Comparing two dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, comparison

I have a text file containing a text description of different objects in an image. For instance, this is the text of file which  describes an image containing image1 & image2 .. which have circles of varying length.

```
Image1
    a
        shape:circle
        size:huge
        fill:no
    b
        shape:circle
        size:very large
        fill:no
        inside:a
    c
        shape:circle
        size:large
        fill:no
        inside:a,b
  Image2
    f
        shape:circle
        size:large
        fill:no
    g
        shape:circle
        size:medium
        fill:no
        inside:f
    h
        shape:circle
        size:small
        fill:no
        inside:f,g
```

What could be an efficient (and non-ugly) way to compare these two and describe the similarities and differences. the images are read into dictionaries and this is i am comparing them. The attributes contain all the infomration read from the text file.

```
    for attrib, value in Image1.objects.iteritems():
            for key2,value2 in Image2.objects.iteritems():
                for o1, o2 in zip(value.attributes.iteritems(),value2.attributes.iteritems()):
                    if o1 == o2:
                        print 'ok', o1 , o2
                    else:
                        print 'nok', o1, o2
```

here is the output of this loop:

```
ok ('shape', 'octagon') ('shape', 'octagon')
ok ('size', 'very large') ('size', 'very large')
```

Eventually I want to get a description (may be a list or dictionary??) of what was added in image2, what was removed , what was modified ...